# OpenLayers2 No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

I am trying to update a (several year old) OL2 JS app with a new OSM layer

My layer code is:

```
                        var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
                                "Hydda",
                                ["http://a.tile.openstreetmap.se/hydda/full/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"],
                                {crossOriginKeyword: null}
                        )
```

I cannot get the tiles to load without the following error:

> Image from origin 'http://a.tile.openstreetmap.se' has been blocked
>   from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://mysite' is therefore not allowed access.

Any ideas? The crossOriginKeyword declaration should handle this, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently related to a corporate firewall misconfiguration, and not a result of OpenLayers config.

Comment: Can you tell more about how did you resolve, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: The corporate firewall was not allowing traffic out in some circumstances that it should have. Wish I knew more details (not my job).

Answer (score 0):

Your call is missing  `tileOptions {}`

```
 var layerOSM2 = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(
    "Hydda",
    ["http://a.tile.openstreetmap.se/hydda/full/${z}/${x}/${y}.png"],
    {tileOptions: 
       {crossOriginKeyword: null}
    }
 );
```

Comment: Interesting-- the same code worked the next day when the firewall was reconfigured. I guess it didn't have to do with crossOrigin at all.

Comment: MAybe you did not run into the same issue as I did OR you managed to fix the cors issue in the meantime OR maybe both syntaxes are ok.